# windows xp prof. machine turns off

Tags: windows-xp

My windows xp prof. machine, which I have been using for a while, started to turn itself off recently after some time. I doubt that it is an overheating issue as all fans seem to work nicely. What else should I have a look at? Thanks!

Christian

Comment: By powering itself off, do you mean it is shutting down cleanly (running the shutdown sequence / ACPI off) or going off instantly?

Comment: going off instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Log files. Power to the unit, not a tripped circuit breaker. UPS isn't going bad. Reseat cables. BIOS logging, if there is any.

You don't mention how old the computer is, but it's possible the power supply is going bad.

When's the last time it's been cleaned out? Dust could be blocking vents and airflow.

Are you running temp monitoring software?

Did you check that the cooling on the CPU is adequate still, not coming loose?

Comment: I changed the power supply and that seems to have solved it.

Comment: Actually it just did it again. Mmmmmhh .... will try the cpu temp software check

Comment: I changed the cpu fan and thinks seem to be ok so far so will accept your answer